# Interfêrencia entre CSS3 transition e Jquery animate

Tags: jquery, css3, animação

Estou programando um site de uma página que navega por hashs usando as ferramentas disponíveis para animação do CSS3 combinando transition e transform. Usando Less o código dos mixins ficam mais ou menos assim:

```
.transitionSet (@prop: all, @time: 1s, @ease: linear) {
  -webkit-transition: @prop @time @ease;
  -moz-transition: @prop @time @ease;
  -o-transition: @prop @time @ease;
  -ms-transition: @prop @time @ease;
  transition: @prop @time @ease;
}
```

O que acontece é que por CSS3 não consigo animar o scroll da página ao clicar no menu. O caminho é usar Jquery:

```
function ScrollPage(page){
    var FromTop=$(page).offset().top;
    $(document.body).animate({
        scrollTop:FromTop
    }, 1000);
}
```

O que acontece é que quando as animações ocorrem juntas a rolagem e as animações em CSS3 ficam lentas, o que não não é muito além de pequenos efeitos.

Gostaria de saber o que fazer para que as duas animações ocorram de modo suave e sem delay.

Comment: Confuso demais. Não entendi onde entra o less nessa história. E você quer **evitar** que duas animações ocorram suave e sem delay? Por que não explica melhor o que você pretende fazer, talvez existam outras formas e propostas melhores de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Mencionei o Less pelo fato de renderizar o CSS na página. Fato! Excluí diretamente o CSS renderizado por ele e o scroll da página funcionou perfeitamente. Less seria uma informação adicional que pode ajudar quem tentar me ajudar. Como disse na pergunta, a página fica lenta quando as duas animaões distintas (CSS3 transition e jQuery animate) ocorrem juntas. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma incompatibilidade e como resolver para que as animações ocorram de forma perfeita.